# How much space does a GPT partition table take up?

Tags: partitioning, storage, gpt

When you create a GPT partition table on a storage drive, how much of the space is used up by GPT itself? I'm assuming it's on the order of megabytes.

I'm mostly just curious, but when I search this online, I can only find information about the maximum size of a disk that GPT can work with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### How much (of the) space is used up by GPT itself?

> I'm assuming it's on the order of megabytes.

No, it is much smaller:

> In 64-bit Windows operating systems, 16,384 bytes, or 32 sectors, are reserved for the GPT, leaving LBA 34 as the first usable sector on the disk.

Source [GUID partition table| DiskInternals](https://www.diskinternals.com/glossary/guid_partition_table/)

[image]

> Note: The green block represents the Primary GPT, the blue block
>   represents the secondary GPT (which is located at the end of the
>   disk).
>
> The GPT uses a modern system of Logical Block Addressing (LBA) rather
>   than the outdated CHS (Cylinder-Head-Sector) method, used in MBR.
>   Passed down from its predecessor, block LBA 0 contains MBR, with the
>   Primary GPT Header in LBA 1. Following the GPT Header is the partition
>   table itself. In the 64-bit version of Microsoft Windows NT, the GPT
>   reserves the first 32 sectors, so that the first used sector on every
>   hard drive is LBA 34.
>
> That aside, the GPT provides data duplication; the header and
>   partition table are stored both at the start and the end of the disk.

Source [NTFS information: Hard Disk Drive Basics](http://www.ntfs.com/guid-part-table.htm)

---

#### Further reading

- [A comparison of GPT and MBR partition structures - gHacks Tech News](https://www.ghacks.net/2017/04/27/a-comparison-of-gpt-and-mbr-partition-structures/)
- [Frequently asked questions about the GUID Partitioning Table disk architecture](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/302873/frequently-asked-questions-about-the-guid-partitioning-table-disk-arch)

Comment: So the secondary GPT entries are just duplicates of the first ones?

Comment: "the GPT provides data duplication; the header and partition table are stored both at the start and the end of the disk." so yes.

Comment: @AaronFranke Note that `16,384 bytes` assumes the logical block size to be 512 bytes, which is not always the case.

Comment: A `sgdisk` backup of a GPT just gave me 20Kbytes of output.